# Running Order by on column alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run following SQL query on northwind database :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Joinning DESC) rownum,
    LastName, Country, HireDate AS Joinning
   FROM  Employees
   WHERE  Region IS NOT NULL
   ) r
```

It's giving me the error :

```
Invalid column name 'Joinning'.
```

The 'rownumber' is required for pagination.

Can anybody please suggest how I can sort on the Joining alias with the rownumber generated ?

**--A possible work around**

Just figured out a work around; please suggest if anything is wrong or need changes :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Joinning DESC) rownum,* FROM (
    SELECT  
    LastName, Country, HireDate AS Joinning

   FROM  Employees
   WHERE  Region IS NOT NULL
   ) r
```

**--To put further where clause on row number(what I wanted to do for pagination):**

```
With myres as(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Joinning DESC) rownum,* FROM (
    SELECT  
       LastName, Country, HireDate AS Joinning
       FROM  Employees
       WHERE  Region IS NOT NULL
     ) a
) Select * from myres where myres.rownum > 0 and myres.rownum < = 0+20
```

Comment: be careful on where you use the aliases, try using HireDate instead of Joinning in the Order By clause.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` will enumerate all rows returned with a unique number. That happens before the `DISTINCT` is considered so to save yourself from an unnecessary "Distinct Sort" operator in the query plan you should remove `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Why do you even use a subquery? Not necessary imo.

Comment: Thanks for your final solution! It was a fit for my specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HireDate DESC) rownum,
LastName, Country, HireDate AS Joinning
FROM  Employees
WHERE  Region IS NOT NULL
) r
```

Comment: Again, using the original column name is not my concern. Hiredate will be a Sub Query in real case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you ahve joinning in your table.
The order by clause is usually given at the last of the query like this :

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() rownum,
    LastName, Country, HireDate AS Joinning)
   FROM  Employees
   WHERE  Region IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Joinning DESC)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: "The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause"

Answer (score 0):

**Use Original Name of the field, That will work just fine** `HireDate`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HireDate DESC) rownum,
    LastName, Country, HireDate AS Joinning
   FROM  Employees
   WHERE  Region IS NOT NULL
   ) r
```

Comment: I know the original Column name will work fine - but that's not my Qn - HireDate is actually will be a sub query aliased as Joining.